# reverse operation to "Union and find"

Tags: algorithm, find, union

We know there is "Union and find" for disjoint sets.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Union_find

But how to do reverse operation ? Consider a set with N nodes connected with E edges( which is in fact a graph ).
And at each step we want to delete some edge and check if this delete operation leads to have another disjoint set. Is it possible to do it fastly like in "Union and find"?

P.S this is not homework, we have holiday :)

Comment: Since you mentioned **union-find**, in some cases, it is possible to convert this into a standard union-find problem.

Consider a graph *G* and *E'* is an ordered set of edges to be removed. 

Start with the graph with all *E'* edges removed. 

Now, in each step add edges from *E'* in reverse order of removal (the last edge removed is added back to the graph first), and check if union leads to a merge of two disjoint sets. If yes, then removing this edge will create another disjoint set.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is known as the online edge deletion problem or online connectivity problem. Some links to algorithms are in this [section of the Wikipedia article on graph connectivity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connected_component_%28graph_theory%29#Algorithms).

Comment: Thanks for the link. I can only find Articles to buy on ACM. Couldn't find any info on TopCoder, any direct link ?:)

Answer (score 1):

So your question is how to efficiently detect a [Bridge](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bridge_%28graph_theory%29)? This can be done in linear time (also see the link).

Comment: Given that @Chris apparently wants to do the operation repeatedly (he does say "at each step") we can be more efficient that detecting bridges at each stage.

Comment: i think that if you run that bridge finding algorithm and mark the bridges and note that unless a edge is added to a graph no new bridges can appear; all bridges that exist in that graph remain as bridges as edges are removed and new bridges can only appear if you remove an edge which is not a bridge; so you only need to rerun the algorithm on the two subgraphs were connected by a non-bridge edge that was just removed.

Answer (score 1):

Union-find is used in Kruskal algorithm, which repeatedly adds edge of minimum weight which doesn't make a cycle. A reverse idea - removing edges of maximum weight as long as it doesn't disconnect the graph - is used in [reverse-delete algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse-Delete_algorithm#CITEREFThorup2000), which seemingly can make use of some complicated data structure (see Wikipedia).

Comment: Next nice link, but too much generalized and no really code to see :(